# Routing problem in Ubuntu server 17.10

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ethernet

I'm pretty new to Linux and im trying to set up a virtual lab in Hyper-V with a Ubuntu server 17.10 as a router between physical network and my lab network. The server has two interfaces external and private (external being the WAN and internal being LAN)

I have modified my /etc/network/interfaces so that it looks like:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.1.1
        network 192.168.1.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

after that i edited the /etc/sysctl.conf and removed the comment in `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

All instructions I have found imply that after you done this and restart networking (I just reboot server) the second interface should have the ip that it was given, BUT in my case the interface does not come up after reboot and I need to manually raise it up with sudo ifconfig eth1 up. After that when I check my ifconfig the eth1 is shown but is does not have the address I set up but instead it has a ipv6 address

Seems to me that the OS is not reading the /etc/network/interfaces file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ifupdown which uses /etc/network/interfaces was deprecated in 17.10.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Netplan

Instead use /etc/netplan/*netcfg.yaml